# How to prevent responsiveness on vertical resizing of webpage?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

i have a container div with `height: 100%` and body too.
I did that to make it fit the window size, that said, i don't want my page to resize vertically (content going up when resizing)  but only horizontally by triggering media queries.

One issue resulting from that is, virtual keyboard poping up on mobile pushes the content up and the layout of the page gets messy.

Ps: i have the viewport meta tag added to the document

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go fullscreen with sections you will inevitably face issues with different mobile screens and tablets. I've never been a fan of full height pages since they cause alot of trouble with content.

What you can do is set a small height breakpoint and turn the page to *height: auto;* when the keyboard opens.